# want to alter titles on wordpress widgets areas

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a template in wordpress based on the thematic framework.

I want to remove the title from some of the widget areas I have created. This is the widget area that I have created.

```
function tadpole_pagesrighthand() {
register_sidebar(array(
'name' => 'Pages right hand ',
    'id' => 'pages-right-hand',
'description' => __('Pages right hand column', 'thematic'),
'before_widget' => thematic_before_widget(),
'after_widget' => thematic_after_widget(),
'before_title' => tadpole_before_title(),
'after_title' => tadpole_after_title(), )
);
}
```

And in my functions I have:

```
function tadpole_before_title(){
$content='<p>helllo</p>';
}

function tadpole_after_title(){
    $content='<p>goodbye</p>';
}
```

But my content isn't appearing.

I guess I am doing something pretty obvious wrong but I can't see it!

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return` the content you want to be assigned to the sidebar property. You're assigning the variable, but not `return`ing it:

```
function tadpole_before_title() {
    $content = '<p>helllo</p>';
    return $content;
}

function tadpole_after_title() {
    $content = '<p>goodbye</p>';
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: however, what I really wanted to do was stop the title appearing. Its still there = how would I do that.